# How to add parameters to NSURLSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, networking, nsurlsession

When I add a dictionary of parameters in the session configuration and setting the HTTPAdditonalHeaders property, my app crashes with the following error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb0000000000000f2'

The dictionary contains only a string and 1 NSNumber object. I don't know how to solve this. Please help me.

Code:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

NSDictionary *parametersDictionary = @{"firstname": @1, "lastname": @2};
configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = parametersDictionary;

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];

[[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

}] resume];
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add some code?

Comment: @lucianomarisi Yes, there you go!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you can't set `NSNumber`s in your `parametersDictionary` so if you replace the values of your `parametersDictionary` with strings things should work.

Like this:

```
NSDictionary *parametersDictionary = @{"firstname": @"first name value", @"lastname": @"last name value"};
```

Having said that I usually use a JSON payload in the HTTP body to have more flexibility for this sort of example.

Comment: But now it ignores the parameters.

Comment: How do you know that it ignores the parameters? I tried that code with Charles proxy and the parameters were there.

Comment: Because I used NSLog to check the results and the parameters were ignored.

Comment: Ok, can you add the code you use to log the request headers?